# WSO2 EI611 Kafka connector error jaas.conf not found

Tags: wso2, apache-kafka, jaas, connector, wso2-esb

EI611 with kafka connector latest throwing error :

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading
>   Zookeeper JAAS login context 'Client' . . . . Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException:
>   C:\WSO2EI~1.1\bin..\repository\conf\identity\jaas.conf (No such file
>   or directory)

This error was posted by someone else too :
[wso2 Inbound endpoint - Kafka consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46359005/wso2-inbound-endpoint-kafka-consumer)

Does anybody find the solution? Do you know how to fix?

Comment: Ok, so far , I was guided by this doc page : https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Kafka+Inbound+Protocol Suddenly, this page shows in link https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0+Operations .Then proceed with the instructions and hit a wall :  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0+Connector+and+Inbound+Endpoint - it says add the jar for streaming connector to folder , <ESB_HOME>/repository/components/dropins , but there's no folder.  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Kafka+Inbound+Operations. How to keep sanity?

Comment: Here's the simple question : How to add Kafka connector , so an inbound endpoint with kafka listener (withou security) can be tested ? Wha are the required steps to follow? Can somebody cleanup the documentation?

Comment: Anybody from WSO2, even care to reply this? You claim that this is the official user/dev community, but did not care to respond....

Answer (score 2):

**If you need to configure Kafka without security, the recommonded version is 0.8.1.1.**

From Kafka version 0.9 onwards, they have introduced Kafka security mechanism with SSL and SASL, which will be configured via JAAS. So, when configuring Kafka with WSO2 Products (EI, DAS, CEP) you need to add this config file (jaas.conf) to /repository/conf/identity.

In this case, WSO2 product acts as the Kafka client and the configuration in the jaas.conf will be used to login to the kafka server. Please follow the Kafka security documentation [1] for configuring security for server and client.

Example content for jaas.conf file which is configured for SASL/ Plaintext.

```
KafkaServer {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="kafka"
   password="kafka-secret"
   user_kafka="kafka-secret"
   user_ibm="ibm-secret";
};

KafkaClient {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="kafka"
  password="kafka-secret";
};
```

Please note that kafka 0.9 supports only SASL/Kerberos authentication. Please carefully follow the Kafka security documentation related to your Kafka version and configure it properly.

[1] http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#security_sasl