# How to connect WSO2 app with Azure Event Hub using SASL?

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, azure-eventhub, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I can't connect to a Kafka source (Azure Event Hub as Kafka) because it requires SASL authentication.

WSO2sp/Siddhi can read extra configurations on **optional.configuration** parameter; I'm not sure I had set the proper values over there.

I have tried the related question: [WSO2 EI611 Kafka connector error jaas.conf not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846546/wso2-ei611-kafka-connector-error-jaas-conf-not-found)

But this applies to an older version of WSO2.

I think there's a problem with ":" character in string connection:

```
Endpoint=sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=tp-stream;SharedAccessKey=123454tqliUPRM5NrnL3sSDJPpCMpmctogQDqvjlehw=;EntityPath=mapping-raw
```

Because Siddhi uses ":" to separate values as in the next link.
https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-kafka/api/latest/#kafka-source

Also there could be a Kafka version trouble: WSO2 supports Kafka version 0.10.0.0 and Azure Event Hub supports Kafka connection protocol 1.0 and above.

```
@source(
    type='kafka', 
    bootstrap.servers='xxxx.servicebus.windows.net:9093',
    topic.list='mapping-raw',
    group.id='$Default',
    threading.option='single.thread',
    optional.configuration='security.protocol:SASL_SSL,sasl.mechanism:PLAIN,sasl.username:$ConnectionString,sasl.password:Endpoint=sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=tp-stream;SharedAccessKey=123454tqliUPRM5NrnL3sSDJPpCMpmctogQDqvjlehw=;EntityPath=mapping-raw',
 @map(type='json', @attributes( 
    Channel='$.Channel', 
    Application='$.Application',
    SentDate='$.SentDate',
    Process='$.Process',
    EntityType='$.EntityType',
    EntityKey='$.EntityKey',
    Entity = '$.Entity'
    )))

define stream ObjectMappingStream (Channel string, Application string, SentDate string, Process string, EntityType string, EntityKey string, Entity string);
```

I expect to be able to read event from mapping-raw topic.

I get in WSO2 the error:

> Failed to construct kafka consumer